# Displaying an AVFrame on the screen with SDL 2.0

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, yuv, libavformat, video-player

I am working on some code with the help of [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) tutorial and using the latest development libraries of ffmpeg and SDL. I am stuck at the point where I have to display the decoded frame (AVFrame) on the screen. I am inclined to do the above task *i.e*, *Displaying the AVFrame on screen* using the latest API of SDL 2.0 (Using Renderers and Textures alongside the usage of SDL_Window). Frankly speaking, I am not an expert in *SDL_Renderer*, *SDL_Texture*  and the functions associated with them. But I am reading the documentation in the official site of SDL 2.0 and working my way through them.

Is there a way to do the following using SDL 2.0 API  :

- Convert the native frame format to a flavour of **YUV** and display it.

  **(OR)**
- If it is possible, display the frame without having to convert it from native format.

> I want to do the above using Renderers and Textures. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to work with them.

**Can anyone guide me through the steps to do the above tasks?**

PS : Though I have not explicitly tried it, I came across some ways to display AVFrame on the screen by converting the AVFrame format(native) to RGB. But I do not want the native frame format (which is mostly YUV) to RGB conversion, as it is computationally expensive.

Converting between formats is done by sws_scale()

Comment: you can perhaps find some inspiration in my YCbCr (YUV) viewer that displays a fair amount of, well, YUV-formats using SDL. https://github.com/figgis/yuv-viewer

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl, Thanks for the link, but I want to use SDL 2.0 as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of [SDL2's YUV pixel formats](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture#Remarks).

They have several planar and packed variants:

> `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12`: planar mode: Y + V + U (3 planes)
>
> `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV`: planar mode: Y + U + V (3 planes)
>
> `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YUY2`: packed mode: Y0+U0+Y1+V0 (1 plane)
>
> `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UYVY`: packed mode: U0+Y0+V0+Y1 (1 plane)
>
> `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YVYU`: packed mode: Y0+V0+Y1+U0 (1 plane)

Comment: I have tried using that flag. Can you give me a small example with a code snippet ? I do not know how to use it, particularly alongside an AVFrame. I tried searching, but did not find any content.

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/rsaxvc/LowLatencyVideoPrototype/blob/master/viewer_sdl.cpp).  `libav` sometimes likes to emit non-contiguous planar YUV frames so the code around [here](https://github.com/rsaxvc/LowLatencyVideoPrototype/blob/master/viewer_sdl.cpp#L227) makes a SDL-able contiguous buffer.

Comment: @jsp99: SDL2 >= 2.0.1 has [`SDL_UpdateYUVTexture()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateYUVTexture) for updating planar YUV textures so you don't have to manually coalesce `libav`'s buffers any more.